# How to add alternating trigonometric functions to an an array in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

So I would like to add alternating Cos and Tan functions to an array in python with a given size. E.g. I have a numpy array of size (10,5) I want to add for each row, (Tan(a), Cos(a), Tan(a), Cos(a), Tan(a)). Could someone provide a hint as where to begin?

I tried setting a counter that used a while loop on the condition that the counter was less than 5 but this doesn't seem like it will work. Would really appreciate suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
arr[:, ::2] = np.tan(arr[:, ::2])
arr[:, 1::2] = np.cos(arr[:, 1::2])
```

I'm being bold and assuming you're not *very* familiar with **slicing notation and indexing** in numpy, so you can consider going through the docs: [Numpy Indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

Since you asked for alternation, I thought of given a more generic answer with three types of alternation:

- alternating `row`
- alternating `column`  *you asked for this*
- alternating `row` and `column` (both): *like a chess-board*

I will use this dummy data in the subsequent examples: **A**, **B**, **C**

```py
# dummy data
import numpy as np
angles = np.random.rand(5,4) * np.pi
```

### A. Expected output: *alternating row*

```
[[tan, tan, tan, tan],
 [cos, cos, cos, cos],
 [tan, tan, tan, tan],
 [cos, cos, cos, cos],
 [tan, tan, tan, tan]]
```

#### Code:

```py
# import numpy as np
a = np.zeros(angles.shape)
a[0::2, :] = np.tan(angles[0::2, :])
a[1::2, :] = np.cos(angles[1::2, :])
```

### B. Expected output: *alternating column*

```
[[tan, cos, tan, cos],
 [tan, cos, tan, cos],
 [tan, cos, tan, cos],
 [tan, cos, tan, cos],
 [tan, cos, tan, cos]]
```

#### Code:

```py
# import numpy as np
a = np.zeros(angles.shape)
a[:, 0::2] = np.tan(angles[:, 0::2])
a[:, 1::2] = np.cos(angles[:, 1::2])
```

### C. Expected output: *alternating row and column*

```
[[tan, cos, tan, cos],
 [cos, tan, cos, tan],
 [tan, cos, tan, cos],
 [cos, tan, cos, tan],
 [tan, cos, tan, cos]]
```

#### Code:

```py
# import numpy as np
a = np.zeros(angles.shape)
a[0::2, 0::2] = np.tan(angles([0::2, 0::2])) # tan: odd-row, odd-column
a[0::2, 1::2] = np.cos(angles([0::2, 1::2])) # cos: odd-row, even-column
a[1::2, 0::2] = np.cos(angles([1::2, 0::2])) # cos: even-row, odd-column
a[1::2, 1::2] = np.tan(angles([1::2, 1::2])) # tan: even-row, even-column
```

### D. Benefit of using `numpy` vectorization for alternating rows

You can use the following custom-defined function: `custom_trig_func()`. Applying `numpy` functions to numpy arrays are faster if you can skip `for` loops. The more vectorized your code is, the quicker it will run. The approach here avoids using `for` loops and uses in-built vectorization of `numpy.tan` and `numpy.cos`.

```py
custom_trig_func(angles)
```

However, if you just want the minimal lines of code to produce what the custom function does, use this:

```py
# angles is your input ndarray
even_rows = (np.arange(angles.shape[0]) % 2 == 0)
out = np.tan(angles)
out[even_rows, :] = np.cos(angles[even_rows, :])
print(out.shape) # out is your expected output
```

#### Code

```py
import numpy as np

def custom_trig_func(angles: np.ndarray, validate=False) -> np.ndarray:
    """Returns an array of type -> numpy.ndarray and shape -> angles.shape, with 
    - odd rows operated on by numpy.tan() and, 
    - even rows operated on by numpy.cos().
    """

    # determine odd and even row indices
    rows = np.arange(angles.shape[0])
    even_rows = (rows % 2 == 0)
    odd_rows = ~even_rows

    # create output array
    out = np.tan(angles)
    out[even_rows, :] = np.cos(angles[even_rows, :])

    if validate:
        assert np.all(out[odd_rows, :] == np.tan(angles[odd_rows, :])), "Validation error in applying TAN to odd rows"
        assert np.all(out[even_rows, :] == np.cos(angles[even_rows, :])), "Validation error in applying COS to even rows"

    return out

# dummy data
angles = np.random.rand(10,5) * np.pi
# apply custom function
custom_trig_func(angles=angles, validate=True)
```

Comment: @TheQuant Please try it out and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi, I think this creates odd rows that are tan and even that are cos. What I want, sorry if I was unclear, is for each row to have alternating elements of tan and cos based on the index. I.e. for Row 1, index 1 is odd and so we have tan, index 2 is even so its cos. And then repeated for each row

Comment: @TheQuant Okay. I made some changes. Please take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Is this something u r looking for ?

```
import numpy as np
import math
x=np.array([x for x in range(50)]).reshape(10,5)
y=x.copy()
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    y[i][0]=math.tan(x[i][0])
    y[i][1]=math.cos(x[i][1])
    y[i][2]=math.tan(x[i][2])
    y[i][3]=math.cos(x[i][3])
    y[i][4]=math.tan(x[i][4])
print(x)
print(y)




[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14]
 [15 16 17 18 19]
 [20 21 22 23 24]
 [25 26 27 28 29]
 [30 31 32 33 34]
 [35 36 37 38 39]
 [40 41 42 43 44]
 [45 46 47 48 49]]

[[ 0  0 -2  0  1]
 [-3  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  7]
 [ 0  0  3  0  0]
 [ 2  0  0  0 -2]
 [ 0  0 -3  0  0]
 [-6  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  3]
 [-1  0  2  0  0]
 [ 1  0  0  0 -3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can zip through the transposed numpy array and the trigonometric functions (use a list comprehension to fit them with the array shape), my raw attempt:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(50).reshape(10,5)
b = [([np.tan,np.cos]*(round(a.shape[1]//2+1)))[:-1] if a.shape[1] % 2 != 0 else [np.tan,np.cos]*(round(a.shape[1]/2))]
a = np.array([y(x) for x,y in zip(a.T,*b)])
```